# Getting driving directions from google maps V2 in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, directions

i am trying to develop an android app that draws the driving directions between two points. i have successful managed to implement the map but i can't get the directions between two points. i have tried several projects out there but they just don't work.

This is one of the projects i have tried but couldn't get it working:
https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=0B0MdROeR0jbvYTgwTm1IZGNISTQ

Can anyone please help me with this.
Thank you.

Comment: could you post what you have tried?

Comment: sorry, i posted the link of one of the projects i have tried.

Comment: 1. no one is going to download the project and look at it and 2. you need to describe a specific problem you are having

Answer (score 0):

Google Turn-by-turn navigation is not available in Android Map v2. The maximum you can get - is list of points to draw the route, but actual turn-by-turn navigation is not available. You can send an intent to start navigation via google maps though:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=start_lat,start_lon&daddr=end_lat,end_lot"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thank you for your your replay, sorry but i am a bit new in this field. i have managed to create a simple app that displays the maps so  where should i use this intent and what should it display or return to me and how can i get these points of the route. thank you.